# Appropriate Correction for 2 proportion test? --with example--

Tags: proportion, bonferroni, z-test

Below is an example of frequency data between observed and expected proportions. Can I simply run a 2-Proportion z test here? Or, would I be violating assumptions? If I were to run dozens of z tests (i.e. O-E cell comparisons), would I have to correct for multiple comparisons? Is there a better way to do this?

Technically I have 5 different sets of expected proportions -- I am just trying to determine which is most predictive of the observed data.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Would a better solution be to perform a chi-square test on the whole contingency table?

Comment: I suppose I could do a goodness of fit for the whole table, but the residuals (adjusted) would be the equivalent of a z-test, no? Also, the proportions are so small for some of the cells, that I would be well below the minimum acceptable frequency.

Comment: I'm not the best person to answer this, but you could try using referring to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66160/can-i-use-a-two-proportion-z-test?lq=1) and [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-chi-squared-test-and-test-of-equal-proportion).